# PostgreSQL 9.6 crosstab, create pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

How in PostgreSQL 9.6, from a table "import" with structure below in the link...

[image: Structure of 'import' table]

create a query / function, then transpose it to something like this:

[image: Structure of expected view]

Unfortunately, table 'import' has no ID field.
I tried using crosstab with tablefunc, but no effect.

Comment: Please do not use images. Please use text which could be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the opposite of a cross-tab or pivot: you are looking for an un-pivot

In standard SQL you would do this with a UNION ALL (unless the DBMS supports the `unpivot` operator which Postgres does not):

```
select dlimportdate, 1 as colno, col1 as value
from the_table
union all
select dlimportdate, 2, col1
from the_table
union all
...
```

However in Postgres there is a shorter way to do this. Create an array of the columns, then use unnest to turn them into rows:

```
select dlimportdate, t.colno, t.value
from the_table
  cross join unnest(array[col1, col2, col3, ...]) with ordinality as t(value, colno);
```